# How I get Opera correctly working with Privoxy?

Tags: linux, proxy, opera, privoxy

I use Privoxy and recently switched back to Opera as browser. Anything is fine, but one thing is annoying: Everytime I start the computer I have to restart privoxy (`sudo /etc/init.d/privoxy restart`) or Opera shows an error, that it cannot reach the proxy. What is wrong here?

Privoxy is fine by the way the first time, Firefox has no problems working with it.

I'm working on Linux, specifically Ubuntu 10.10.

**EDIT:**

The error-message (in german) is:

> Die Verbindung zum Proxyserver konnte
>   nicht hergestellt werden. Der Zugriff
>   wurde verweigert.
>
> Die von Ihnen aufgerufene Adresse
>   http://www.superuser.com/ ist zurzeit nicht
>   erreichbar. Bitte überprüfen Sie die
>   korrekte Schreibweise der Webadresse
>   (URL) und versuchen Sie dann die Seite
>   neu zu laden. Stellen Sie sicher, dass
>   eine Verbindung mit dem Internet
>   besteht und überprüfen Sie, ob andere
>   Programme mit derselben Verbindung
>   funktionieren. Überprüfen Sie bitte,
>   dass Ihre Einstellungen evtl.
>   zusätzlich installierter
>   Internet-Sicherheitsprogramme korrekt
>   sind, damit Ihnen keine Behinderungen
>   für das normale Web-Browsen entstehen.
>   Wenn Sie sich hinter einer Firewall in
>   einem lokalen Netzwerk befinden und
>   Sie meinen, dass dieses die Probleme
>   verursachen könnte, fragen Sie Ihren
>   System-Administrator. Versuchen Sie
>   nach dem Drücken der Taste F12 und dem
>   Deaktivieren der Proxyserver diese
>   Seite neu zu laden, außer Sie wissen
>   genau, dass Sie diesen Proxy verwenden
>   müssen, um sich mit dem Internet zu
>   verbinden. Benötigen Sie Hilfe? Rufen
>   Sie Operas Hilfe auf. Rufen Sie Operas
>   Online-Supportseiten auf.

That means roughly translated:

> The connection to the proxy-server
>   couldn't established. The access was
>   refused.
>
> The address you want to reach
>   http://superuser.com isn't available
>   at the moment. Please check the
>   correct spelling of the web-address
>   (URL) and then try to reload the site.
>   Make sure, you have access to the
>   Internet and check if other prgrams
>   with the same conenction work. Check
>   eventually the correctness of the
>   preferences of your installed
>   Internet- Security-software, so that
>   no barriers for normal webbrowsing is
>   produced. If you are behind a fireall
>   in a local network and you think, that
>   this could create the problem, ask
>   your system-administrator. Try after
>   pressing F12 and deactivating the
>   proxy-server to reload this site,
>   except you know exactly, that you need
>   this proxy to connect to the Internet.
>   Need Help? Open Opera-Help or Operas
>   Online-support-site.

Comment: Copy-paste the exact error message. Did you change anything to the privoxy configuration?

Comment: To help troubleshoot the problem, if you turn off the proxy setting in Opera, then point Opera back to your Privoxy, does Opera work then or does it say it still can't find the proxy?